# C# LINQ inner object query

Tags: c#, linq, nested, nullreferenceexception

I am too new to LINQ.

```
public static Dictionary<Type, ConfigurationObjectBase> MyDictionary;
```

This expression returns "Object reference not set to an instance of an object":

```
MyDictionary.First(o => o.Value.ID == 12).Key;
```

In fact, the object with ID = 12 is there.

**Update:**

> In fact, the object with ID = 12 is there

it means, there is objects within dictionary where ID is 12.

Comment: We need more code. could you show us where you initialize your dictionary?

Comment: do you have any objects there which are null's?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it would not compile if it was `int?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were no such item, then it would throw **`InvalidOperationException`** with message **"Sequence contains no matching element"**.

It means that either:

- your `Dictionary` is not initialized. You said that there is an object with `ID = 12`. So, it means that is it initialized.
- there is at least one item in your dictionary where a value is `null`. So, while iterating, it tries to access its `Value.ID` and throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Imagine a simple loop over an array:

```
ConfigurationObjectBase Search()
{
    ConfigurationObjectBase[] array = { someObject1, someObject2, null, someObject3 };

    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (item.ID == 12) return item;
        // here, if item is null, you will try to access its ID and get NullReferenceException
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no matching elements");
}
```

Actually, that's what LINQ exactly does. It iterates through the dictionary and once it tries to access a property of `null`, it throws an exception.

You may use the following code to avoid accessing the property of `null`:

```
MyDictionary.First(o => o.Value != null && o.Value.ID == 12).Key;
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is an object with ID 12 it means that your dictionary contains objects which are null. You can filter for them:

```
MyDictionary.Where(x=>x.Value!=null).First(o => o.Value.ID == 12).Key;
```

It will skip all objects with `null` Value. I prefer chaining here, because it shows intention clearly.

EDIT:
as @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev said this answer is good only for small dictionaries. If you want to go with big dictionaries better do:

```
MyDictionary.First(o => o.Value!=null && o.Value.ID == 12).Key;
```

Comment: It will do some redundant iterations. If a `null` item is at the first position, and there are 100000 items in the dictionary - it will do 100001 iteration while it could do 1.